# SVG half circle animation: line cut off

Tags: html, svg

it does not look too bad when the `stroke-width` setting is set to very small numbers (1, 2, 3, ...) but once the number becomes bigger the mistake I made with cutting off "a square" is really visible. How can I avoid this? Is there a way to make a padding instead of a border for example, so the stroke points more inwards? Or is it only doable by reducing the circle radius?

```html
<svg version="1.1" 
     id="foo" 
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
     width="160"
     height="160"
     viewBox="0 0 160 160" >
  <g stroke="black" fill="none" stroke-width="20">
  <path d="M 0 80 A 80 80 0 0 1 80 0"/>
  </g>
      <animateTransform 
         attributeName="transform" 
         attributeType="XML" 
         type="rotate"
         dur="2s" 
         from="0 0 0"
         to="360 0 0" 
         repeatCount="indefinite" />
</svg>
```

Comment: To understand what happens add a border to the svg element. The animation you are using is rotating the svg element and since the stroke is very thick some of it is overflowing outside the svg canvas. You may try to add  overflow: visible for the svg element. If your intention is to rotate the path move the animation inside the path element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like enxaneta says in the comments, your path overflows

```html
<svg width="160" height="160" style="background:pink"
     viewBox="0 0 160 160" >
  <g stroke="black" fill="none" stroke-width="20">
  <path d="M 0 80 A 80 80 0 0 1 80 0" />
  </g>
      <animateTransform 
         attributeName="transform" 
         type="rotate" dur="10s" 
         from="0 0 0" to="360 0 0" 
         repeatCount="indefinite" />
</svg>
```

easiest solution is to make the `viewBox` bigger:

```html
<svg width="160" height="160" style="background:pink"
     viewBox="-10 -10 170 170" >
  <g stroke="black" fill="none" stroke-width="20">
  <path d="M 0 80 A 80 80 0 0 1 80 0" />
  </g>
      <animateTransform 
         attributeName="transform" 
         type="rotate" dur="10s" 
         from="0 0 0" to="360 0 0" 
         repeatCount="indefinite" />
</svg>
```